# insert image sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

i have some pictures and i want to store it in sqlite

what i need to do

Comment: I know, but I won't say until you accept some answers. (When an answer satisfies your question, you can click the green tick next to it.)

Comment: @Marcelo: out of curiosity, why?

Comment: I thought it would be obvious. Most regulars avoid answering OP's who don't accept answers. It's a fairly effective way to encourage doing the right thing. The only difference, perhaps, is that they don't state it quite as blatantly as I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two schools of thought

1. Put them in a directory and then store the path in a text field
2. Store the image data in a blob field

If the database is very large and the images are too, then the file system way is more performant.

If you just want something done quick, use a blob.  It's ok, but doesn't scale as well.

Comment: but why did people said 'blob' will make your sqlite laggy? is there any solution for this case?

Comment: Put the images on the file system and store paths in the database. 

Relational Databases really like simple, constant sized rows. They can handle blobs, but that’s not what they are best at.

Answer (score 1):

For detail follow site:
http://blog.developeronhire.com/create-sqlite-table-insert-into-sqlite-table/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function createDatabase(){
  try 
  {
     if(window.openDatabase)
     {
         var shortName   =  'db_edentiti';
         var version   =  '1.0';
         var displayName  =  'Edentiti Information';
         var maxSize   =  65536; // in bytes
         db      =  openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
     }
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

function executeQuery($query,callback){
  try
  {
    if(window.openDatabase){

      db.transaction(
        function(tx){
          tx.executeSql($query,[],function(tx,result){
            if(typeof(callback) == "function"){
              callback(result);
            }else{
              if(callback != undefined){
                eval(callback+"(result)");
              }
            }
         },function(tx,error){});
      });
      return rslt;
    }
  } catch(e){}
}

function createTable(){
  var sql = 'drop table image';
  executeQuery(sql);
  var sqlC = 'CREATE TABLE image (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, image BLOB )';
  executeQuery(sqlC);
}

function insertValue(){
  var img = document.getElementById('image');
  var sql = 'insert into image (name,image) VALUES ("sujeet","'+img+'")';
  executeQuery(sql,function(results){alert(results)});
}

<input type="button" name='create' onClick="createDatabase()" value='Create Database'>
<input type="button" name='create' onClick="createTable()" value='create table'>
<input type="button" name='insert' onClick="insertValue()" value='Insert value'>
<input type="button" name='select' onClick="showTable()" value='show table'>
<input type="file" id="image" >
<div result></div>
```