# How to insert images into the SqLite DB

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [insert image sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295166/insert-image-sqlite)

I wanted to know how we can insert images into the database. We cannot drag & drop it into the cell i have tried it. Can some one help me out.

Thank you and any help is appreciable.

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295166/insert-image-sqlite

Comment: Please do little search before asking any question.There are lots of links related to your question.

Comment: please use some research, Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better to store the `image name` and you should `store image` into `storage device` so that you can access your image using name and can fetch otherwise it will grow you `sqllite` database which will be not `light` then 
and will be more problematic for your programming to

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to convert bitmap image to base64 string and store it into sqlite, and decode it again to bitmap where ever needed